# Convert date in date list condition to list of date ranges

Tags: mysql, performance, date, condition, query-performance

I want to look for all the records that occur on specific dates.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE date(column) in ($date1, $date2, ...);
```

However, as many of you, know this kind of comparison doesn't get along with indexes. So, I was wondering if there is a simple way to convert this query to something of the style of the following query without too much effort (i.e., : not using an external tool).

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE (column >= $date1 AND column < $date1 + interval 1 day)
   OR (column >= $date2 AND column < $date2 + interval 1 day)
   ...
```

So the optimizer can still use the indexes. (I'm using MySQL, but ANSI SQL would be great)

Comment: Why do you think your proposed approach will "get along with indexes" better?

Comment: Because indexes break when you apply date function on timestamp or datetime fields.

Comment: In the first query of your question you use the `date()` function (apparently to convert `column` to the `date` data type), while in the second query you don't, and then you say that the use of `date()` "breaks indexes". So why do you use it in the first place, if (as follows from the second query) it is not necessary?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## SUGGESTION #1

```
SELECT A.* FROM table1 A INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT '2015-03-01' dtcolumn
    UNION SELECT '2015-03-15'
    UNION SELECT '2015-04-01'
    UNION SELECT '2015-04-15'
    UNION SELECT '2015-05-01'
) B ON
A.dtcolumn >= B.dtcolumn
AND A.dtcolumn < B.dtcolumn + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

## SUGGESTION #2

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE
(column >= '2015-03-01' AND
column < '2015-03-01' + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
UNION
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE
(column >= '2015-03-15' AND
column < '2015-03-15' + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
UNION
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE
(column >= '2015-04-01' AND
column < '2015-04-01' + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
UNION
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE
(column >= '2015-04-15' AND
column < '2015-04-15' + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
UNION
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE
(column >= '2015-05-01' AND
column < '2015-05-01' + INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Comment: I prefer Suggestion #1. I think it's more clear.

Comment: And more "maintaneable" if you can call this a mainteneable query.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:
(I did this on Oracle, it should mostly work elsewhere, the WITH clauses are mostly for just faking sample data .. so not entirely necessary)

```
  with w_date_list as (  -- just some sample input dates - these are from your IN list (note that you want to re-org them as a "table" not an IN list - there's ways of doing that if you need help with that step
        select to_date('01-apr-2015','dd-mon-yyyy') cdate from dual union all
        select to_date('02-apr-2015','dd-mon-yyyy') cdate from dual union all
        select to_date('03-apr-2015','dd-mon-yyyy') cdate from dual union all
        select to_date('04-apr-2015','dd-mon-yyyy') cdate from dual union all
        select to_date('05-apr-2015','dd-mon-yyyy') cdate from dual
        ),
        w_date_rng as (      -- re-organize them into ranges using LEAD analytic function
           select cdate start_date, 
                  nvl(lead(cdate) over (order by cdate), cdate + 1 )  end_date  -- last one, just default to 1 day
             from w_date_list
           )
  select *
    from (select to_date('01-jan-2015 03:14:46','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') yourdate from dual union all
          select to_date('01-mar-2015 03:14:46','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') yourdate from dual union all
          select to_date('01-apr-2015 03:14:46','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') yourdate from dual union all
          select to_date('01-apr-2015 10:14:46','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') yourdate from dual union all
          select to_date('01-apr-2015 13:14:46','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') yourdate from dual union all
          select to_date('02-apr-2015 03:14:46','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') yourdate from dual union all
          select to_date('02-apr-2015 21:14:46','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') yourdate from dual union all
          select to_date('04-apr-2015 03:14:46','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') yourdate from dual union all
          select to_date('04-apr-2015 15:14:46','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') yourdate from dual union all
          select to_date('04-apr-2015 15:14:46','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') yourdate from dual union all
          select to_date('04-apr-2015 15:14:46','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') yourdate from dual union all
          select to_date('05-apr-2015 08:14:46','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') yourdate from dual union all
          select to_date('05-apr-2015 16:14:46','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') yourdate from dual
           ) table1   ,  -- this just some fake data for your "table1" table.
         w_date_rng   wd
   where table1.yourdate between wd.start_date and wd.end_date  -- join the two with range ... it'll use an index on "yourdate" if it exists
  /
```

Results:

```
  YOURDATE             START_DATE           END_DATE
  -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
  01-apr-2015 03:14:46 01-apr-2015 00:00:00 02-apr-2015 00:00:00
  01-apr-2015 10:14:46 01-apr-2015 00:00:00 02-apr-2015 00:00:00
  01-apr-2015 13:14:46 01-apr-2015 00:00:00 02-apr-2015 00:00:00
  02-apr-2015 03:14:46 02-apr-2015 00:00:00 03-apr-2015 00:00:00
  02-apr-2015 21:14:46 02-apr-2015 00:00:00 03-apr-2015 00:00:00
  04-apr-2015 03:14:46 04-apr-2015 00:00:00 05-apr-2015 00:00:00
  04-apr-2015 15:14:46 04-apr-2015 00:00:00 05-apr-2015 00:00:00
  04-apr-2015 15:14:46 04-apr-2015 00:00:00 05-apr-2015 00:00:00
  04-apr-2015 15:14:46 04-apr-2015 00:00:00 05-apr-2015 00:00:00
  05-apr-2015 08:14:46 05-apr-2015 00:00:00 06-apr-2015 00:00:00
  05-apr-2015 16:14:46 05-apr-2015 00:00:00 06-apr-2015 00:00:00

  11 rows selected.
```

This could be "generalized" as:

```
select *
 from table1   ,
      ( select cdate start_date, 
               nvl(lead(cdate) over (order by cdate), cdate + 1 )  end_date 
          from (  select to_date('01-apr-2015','dd-mon-yyyy') cdate from dual union all
                  select to_date('02-apr-2015','dd-mon-yyyy') cdate from dual union all
                  select to_date('03-apr-2015','dd-mon-yyyy') cdate from dual union all
                  select to_date('04-apr-2015','dd-mon-yyyy') cdate from dual union all
                  select to_date('05-apr-2015','dd-mon-yyyy') cdate from dual
                  )  w_date_list
        )   wd
where table1.yourdate between wd.start_date and wd.end_date  
/
```

That should work on any DB ... MYSQL, Oracle, whatever.

just need to input the date list range - it would be best to feed it in as another table or such ...

I could show how to do it Oracle but probably not terribly useful to you :) Might need another question for that if needed.

Comment: Thank you @ypercube for noting this answer is not broad enough. And just to note, mysql does not support "with" statement (even though it's SQL-99 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324935/mysql-with-clause) so it would be neccesary to use a subselect.

Comment: Well, I used the WITH statement mostly as a place holder for data, but sure, I'll update that .. ;)

Comment: My comment was not (only) about `with`. `nvl()` and `to_date()` are proprietary Oracle functions. `with` and `lead()` and `over` are standard SQL but not implemented in MySQL. This answer might be fine for Oracle but needs substantial changes and effort to make it work in MySQL. Only `dual` would work as it is (although it's another non-standard feature.)

Comment: Apart from that, the `between` is just wrong. The OP has correctly used `>=` and `<` in the question, there is no reason to change it. And I don't see why we need to use `lead()` anyway, It seems to change what the OP wants to something else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm agree with second suggestion of RolandoMySQLDBA answer that using `UNION` instead of `OR` makes the seeking of the results too faster, And also we know:

> The default behavior for **`UNION`** is that *duplicate rows* are *removed* from the result. The optional `DISTINCT` keyword has no effect other than the default because it also specifies duplicate-row removal. With the optional `ALL` keyword, duplicate-row removal does not occur and the result includes all matching rows from all the `SELECT` statements.

And as your requirement I think your dates are in a separate sequence that will not make any duplicate row, So, for avoiding that *duplicate-row removal* that contains a hidden order by and etc. within it, I suggest you to use *`UNION ALL`* instead of *`UNION`*, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE (column >= $date1 AND column < $date1 + interval 1 day)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE (column >= $date2 AND column < $date2 + interval 1 day)
UNION ALL
...
```